# Docker-compose: display effective configuration?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Both the docker and docker-compose documentation discuss usage of multiple `yaml` files as a means to customize configuration.  Functionally this all works great.  Originally there was this:

```
docker-compose -f standard-run-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

and

```
docker-compose -f debug-run-docker-compose.yml up -d
```

as you would suspect there was almost complete overlap between the two `yaml` files.  For example, `service2` in the debug `yml` was only different because of the `environment` section:

```
service2:
  environment: {MAX_MEMORY: 2048m, CATALINA_OPTS: '-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=16543' }
```

This change lowers the amount of memory compared with the production setting and adds the parameters required to start in `debug` mode.  To improve I did:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.std.yml -f docker-compose.debug.yml up -d
```

It seems to work perfectly - the second file only contains the changes - thus there is no more overlap of data, it is DRY.   However, when I do:

```
docker-compose config
```

It does not give me the config of the actual RUNNING configuration, rather it simply gives the config of the first `yaml` file.   In order to test, I want to be able to compare the original debug config with my multiple file one.  Is there any way to output that "effective" config from `docker-compose`?   I am running version 1.20.

Comment: You have to provide all files to the docker-compose script using the -f switches when running the config (or any other directive). By default only the docker-compose.yml is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I was so lame!  Yes, this works:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.std.yml -f docker-compose.debug.yml config
```

FWIW, that docker-compose has WAY more many downvotes than up!  :)